# Анимация из центра экрана

Tags: android

Как можно сделать так, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку, из центра экрана плавно выводилась ImageView. Т.е. изначально ImageView скрыт, а при нажатии на некую кнопку из центра экрана этот ImageView плавно появляется постепенно увеличиваясь до определенного размера. На рисунке примерная схема чего хочется. Зеленые это кнопки, а ImageView должен появляться поверх них

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Посмотрите в сторону вот этого [примера](https://developer.android.com/training/animation/zoom.html). Похоже то, что вам нужно, слегка доработать.

Comment: Спасибо. Буду разбираться.